# How many ways are there to split 16 people into 8 pairs? And split the 16 again so nobody have the same teammate again

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

(The order of the couples and the person's inside the couple dosnt matter)
I know the first divide will be $\frac{16!}{8!\cdot 2^8}$.

But how many options do I have to split the $16$ people again so nobody have the same teammate again.

Comment: You are correct in the first part (*though I would prefer to write this as $15!!$ using double-factorial notation*).  As for the second part, do you have reason to believe this should be easily answerable?

Comment: My first instinct would be inclusion-exclusion for the second part, i.e. counting the number of ways such that at least one pair is repeated.

Comment: @ADMATAI: Please clarify the intent of your question, prferably with a small example with $4$ or $6$ people instead of $16$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume in the first pairings that person1 is paired with person2, that person3 is paired with person4, and in general person $2i$ is paired with person $2i-1$.  Apply inclusion-exclusion over the events that at least one of the pairs is repeated in the new pairing.

With $k$ pairs repeated, we pick which $k$ pairs those are in $\binom{8}{k}$ ways.  Those $2k$ people are thus not available to be paired any longer.  Pair the remaining $16-2k$ people in $(16-2k-1)!!$ ways.  This gives the total of:

$$15!! - 8\cdot 13!! + \binom{8}{2}11!!-\binom{8}{3}9!!+\dots\pm \binom{8}{k}(16-1-2k)!!\pm\dots$$

$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^8(-1)^{k}\binom{8}{k}(16-2k-1)!! = 1190672$$

That is, given a specific first set of pairings, there are 1190672 additional pairings which avoid having repeated any particular pair from the original.  If you are asking how many ways to choose both a first *and* a second set of pairings, then multiply this result by the number of ways to have selected an initial set of pairings, i.e. multiply the result by $15!!$

Comment: For those who are not familiar with double factorial :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial